# Eclipse plugin for javascript development in jsp?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, plugins

I'm used to Intellij to develop javascript but today (or in a short while), I'll need to develop it in Eclipse. A quick google search gave me JSEclipse and JSEditor.
I'm writing JS in JSPs, not necessarily in .js files (even if I might, too).
Among important criterias :

- ctrl + click navigation between function declaration/calls
- variable hightlighting
- Synthax correction

Usual stuff I find in java development and that would be useful in javascript.
Hope this question isn't to general/subjective.

So what should I use ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Aptana Studio plugin for Eclipse. It contains all you need to work with Web Technology.

Comment: I'll have a look when I have time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aptana-3#.U_2OuWOVLIU][1]

This will be helpfull. I got solution by this